# Irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ & $\mathbb{Q}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

Since I'm new into this type of fields, excuse my lack of knowledge. I'm ambitious and want to learn more about it.

My problem: How can I show, f(x)= $x^2+6$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ ?

It's easy to show over $\mathbb{Q}$, but how about a rational 2-adic field?

I think first I have to look at it in 2-adic integer Ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: A quadratic is irreducible over a given field unless it has a zero in that field. What would be the valuation $|\alpha|_p$ of an eventual root $\alpha$ of $f$?

Comment: I don't get your point. Why we talking about the valuation of a root of $f$?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374654/irreducible-polynomials-over-mathbbq-p) for monic irreducible quadratic polynomials over $\Bbb Q_p$

Comment: To prove that the root does not exist in $\Bbb{Q}_p$.